# grease pencil stroke on surface how to match on surface?

Tags: grease-pencil

hi I would like to ask how to match grease pencil precisely on surface    where should I adjust? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose `Surface` in the Stroke Placement menu, there appears an option `Offset` beneath. This controls the distance to your surface.

[image]

Note: in Camera View the offset varies when you zoom in or out. So it is best to use Orthographic View (`Numpad 5`) for drawing on surfaces. In that view the offset stays constant.

Comment: thank you very much